# Line with all alphabets?

Tags: english

What is your smallest line which consists of all the letters at least once? (which all alphabets(a-z) are used).

Please write the meaningful line.

Comment: ^^ line means sentence right?

Comment: yes, I want sentence/line.

Comment: many possible answers... too broad maybe...

Comment: http://clagnut.com/blog/2380/#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29

Comment: See as well http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167709/a-perfect-honest-pangram-that-is-understandable-for-a-regular-native-user.

Comment: Why did you accept a longer sentence when an equal length sentence and a shorter one were both given?

Comment: i have written smallest line and meaningful line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [website](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-shortest-sentence-that-has-all-26-letters-in-the-English-alphabet) that lists common pangrams.  The shortest one listed was -

> Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow”: Used by Adobe In Design to display font samples. (29 letters)

Answer (score 3):

> Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz.

"An eccentric person was frustrated by symbols on a steep slope on the side of a river."

It uses all 26 letters exactly once.

Comment: Deleted comment.  I read the translation, not the original.

Comment: what's the meaning of your line.

Comment: @Ankit: It means "An eccentric person was frustrated by symbols on a steep slope on the side of a river," just like the post says.

Answer (score 1):

well known line :

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

and

> Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack

[lot more references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)